# I need guidance formating output with an sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current SQL looks like this:

```
Declare @Start datetime;
Declare @End datetime;

set @Start = '2016-04-4';
set @End = '2016-04-10';


Select pr.PR_FIELD03 AS EENo, pr.PR_Name AS EEName, lo.LocationName AS [State], SUM(ts.TotalMins/60) AS Hours, ts.OTFlag from TimeSheets as ts
join BWSPRMSD as pr on ts.EmployeeSSN = pr.PR_SSN
join Locations as lo on ts.LocationID = lo.LocationID
where ts.TransDate >= @start AND ts.TransDate <= @End AND ts.ActiveFlag = 1 AND HolidayFlag = 0 AND VacationFlag = 0
group by pr.PR_FIELD03, pr.PR_Name, lo.LocationName, ts.OTFlag;
```

**UPDATED**

That will give me:

```
EENo    EEName      State    Hours    OTFlag
118     Randy       TX       31       1
118     Randy       TX       40       0
118     Randy       MS       40       0
125     Bill        OK       40       0
```

What I need is:

```
EENo    EEName      Reg Hours      O.T. Hours    State
118     Randy       40             31            TX
118     Randy       40             0             MS
125     Bill        40             0             OK
```

Any suggestions you may have would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I apologize because my original post wasn't very clear. No, I don't want to just change column names, I need Hours split on the same line by if the OTFlag is set.

As an aside, If linq or Lambda is your cup of tea. Those answers will work just as well.

Comment: You want the columns to have different names or the data in a different format?

Comment: Randy, just imagine someone who is not sitting besides you... No idea what data comes out of your query, no idea what you want... Please try to ask your questions in a way, that people have a chance to understand your needs... Your update clearifys nothing at all... Please add some sample data below your column names and how this should look like (*What I have* and *What I want*)

Comment: What's your table structure? ts.TotalMins/60 seems to be your OT time only. Where are your regular minutes spent?

Comment: What do you want? A single line for each employee? If you're wanting the state as well, you may have multiple employee lines if they put time in different states.

Comment: You seem to think, that there is kind of implicit sort order... So: If the OTFlag is set, take the hours  as O.T. Hours and pick the next line as Hours. But your rows might pop up in any random order. How should the logic know which two rows are to be "merged"?

Comment: Merge Hours by Employee and by State on the same record/line.

Comment: That Randy is really impressive. He's worked 111 hours in one week. He needs a raise. Also, since all your locations are in the US, someone should probably contact the State Labor Department wherever your company is located; they're probably violating all kinds of laws and statutes making him work that many hours in that short a time period. To the question asked: you need a CASE statement in your SELECT to distribute across columns based on the employee ID.

Comment: Yeah, definitely using CTE to merge those onto the same line. Look at the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed with a CTE. I haven't double checked my code, but it should be pretty close! Assuming here that you have a flag on your timesheet table named OTFlag set to 0 when regular hours are entered and set to 1 when they are OT hours. This way, you will have one entry for each employee for each state they worked in.

```
Declare @Start datetime;
Declare @End datetime;

set @Start = '2016-04-4';
set @End = '2016-04-10';

with regHours as (SELECT ts.employeeSSN, CAST(decimal(5,2),SUM(ts.totalMins/60) AS RegHours , lo.locationName as State
FROM TimeSheets ts
join Locations as lo on ts.LocationID = lo.LocationID
where ts.TransDate >= @start 
AND ts.TransDate <= @End 
AND ts.ActiveFlag = 1 
AND ts.OTFlag = 0
AND HolidayFlag = 0 
AND VacationFlag = 0
Group BY ts.employeeSSN, lo.locationName)



 Select pr.PR_FIELD03 AS EENo
       , pr.PR_Name AS EEName           
       , rh.regHours as 'Regular Hours'
       , SUM(ts.TotalMins/60) AS 'O.T. Hours'
       , lo.LocationName AS [State]
from TimeSheets as ts
join BWSPRMSD as pr on ts.EmployeeSSN = pr.PR_SSN
join Locations as lo on ts.LocationID = lo.LocationID
join regHours rh ON rh.employeeSSN = ts.employeeSSN AND rh.State = ts.LocationID
where ts.TransDate >= @start 
AND ts.TransDate <= @End 
AND ts.ActiveFlag = 1 
AND HolidayFlag = 0 
AND VacationFlag = 0
group by pr.PR_FIELD03, pr.PR_Name, lo.LocationName, rh.RegHours
```

Comment: This CTE logic should get your OT hours and Regular hours on the same line. Alternatively, a cross apply to timesheet table could've worked.

Comment: Not at work right now... @WickedFan this looks 100% better than what I came up with.

Comment: Noticed your edits. Glad it's what I've assumed lol! Alternatively, you could one-up this even more by concatenating the states together if the location is irrelevant.